Classical guitar top dome
I recently purchased a Saers M900M double top classical guitar (used, 2023). When I hold the guitar up to view how flat the top is behind the bridge, it is slightly domed from one side to the other. Clearance at the low E string at the 12th fret is about 4.5mm and just under 4mm at the high E. It plays well and has a nice tone with good projection. I'm assuming the dome is normal but I don't know classical guitar construction well enough to be sure. Can anyone confirm either way, please.

Pleased see attached image of guitar top

What’s the typical relative humidity in the area where the guitar has recently been stored?

Not sure but it was shipped from the Orlando area.

Having a dome up behind the bridge with a scoop in front of the bridge is fairly common on older classical guitars. Over time, and in certain conditions the tension on the face causes this "belly".
On a newer guitar you should not see much or any face deflection. I can't tell from your picture, but if a new guitar came in to my shop with lifting on the face, I would check for heat damage, loose face bracing, and if the bridge is lifting or is properly glued.
In many cases, as long as the guitar doesn't need structural repair, the face will stabilize and work fine.  I usually recommend low tension strings if it is showing lifting.
